# jenkins cannot login after migration

Tags: jenkins

I have migrated my jenkins environment by copying the whole /var/lib/jenkins directory. Now after that i can open the website of jenkins, but after logging nothing happens. If I provide valid creditentials the site starts to load but nothing happens, after providing invalid login and pass the site returns message with information to try again (so jenkins somehow works by checking username and password, but doesn't load main page).

I need help with solving this problem. Could you help me? My log file (last few lines) looks like this:

```
INFO: Completed initialization
Jun 03, 2016 4:15:35 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@bfff1c: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Fri Jun 03 16:15:35 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Jun 03, 2016 4:15:35 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@bfff1c]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@c0c0ee4
Jun 03, 2016 4:15:35 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@c0c0ee4: defining beans [filter,legacy]; root of factory hierarchy
Jun 03, 2016 4:15:35 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
Jun 03, 2016 4:15:35 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Listed all plugins
Jun 03, 2016 4:15:35 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Prepared all plugins
Jun 03, 2016 4:15:35 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started all plugins
Jun 03, 2016 4:15:35 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Augmented all extensions
Jun 03, 2016 4:15:35 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Loaded all jobs
Jun 03, 2016 4:15:35 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Completed initialization
Jun 03, 2016 4:15:35 PM hudson.WebAppMain$3 run
INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running
[06/03/16 16:15:36] SSH Launch of slave-01 on 192.168.14.11 failed in 2,482 ms
[06/03/16 16:15:36] SSH Launch of slave1 on 192.x.x.x failed in 2,483 ms
[06/03/16 16:15:36] SSH Launch of slave2 on 192.x.x.x failed in 2,484 ms
```

As you can see the initialization completed without errors.

I have installed jenkins on ubuntu with this tutorial:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu + of course openjdk-7-jre and openjdk-7-jdk are also installed.

Comment: 1. Did you change the host server? I would make sure I cleared all cache and cookies from the browser. 2. /var/lib/jenkins is your JENKINS_HOME directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migrating your directories without knowing which information you're moving is not the best practice. under your *$JENKINS_HOME* you will have a file called **config.xml**. Open it and search for `<useSecurity>` tag. Change it to disabled - This will give you access to your Jenkins as anonymous.

Go to *Manage Jenkins* -> *Security* and enter your credentials (or configure your security method of your choice) and save it, that should solve your issue.